# Why isn't the background image being loaded in Internet Explorer when it is being loaded in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

Given below is my code.

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Hangman - FoxWay</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>

    <script src='script_hangman.js'></script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()" style="background-image:url(Hangman.jpeg);">

<h2><a href="index.html">FoxWay</a><span id="game_title">Hangman</span> </h2>


<hr>

<div>

    <input id="in" type="text" value="Enter your letter here" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13&&chance<9&&win==0)check();"/>
    <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="check()">Check</button>

    <div>

    <p id="display1">Results:
</p>

    <p id="blanks"></p>
    <p id="display2">Letters used:</p>
    </div>
</div>

<br>


<hr>


</body>

</html>
```

I want to add a background image to this HTML page. The HTML file and the image are located in the same directory. The problem is that this code does load the image in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer. Why is this so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Checked the console for errors? Also, sure it's `Hangman.jpeg` and not `Hangman.jpg`?

Comment: That should work. Look at the Net tag in your developer tools. Do you see the request for the image? Do you get the response you expect?

Comment: Did you try `style="background-image:url('Hangman.jpeg');"`

Comment: @stackunderflow — Why would adding a pair of entirely optional apostrophes help? There aren't any special characters in the URL.

Comment: @Quentin How do I get to my developer tools to look at the Net tag?

Comment: I usually right click and inspect an element, but most browsers let you hit F12 or open them via a menu item.

Comment: @Quentin I think there's no request for the image but there are requests for the CSS file, the javascript file and the HTML file itself.

Comment: The code still being the same, I now observe that the image is being loaded in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

Inlcude the entire path for the image, make sure it's in quotes, and make sure that the CASE of the image name is exactly correct.